# Snowflake: How to extract file name from the empty file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a requirement where input file name has to be captured and stored in the snowflake table. I am using snowflake snowpipe & stage to query the file which is in s3. My code/query works fine when the input file has data, however if the input file is empty, copy command is not getting the file name.

How to get the file name when the input file is empty/zero byte ? Thanks

Snowpipe syntax

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE DEV.schema.load_pipe auto_ingest = true  
AS
COPY INTO schema.TMP_table FROM (
    SELECT 
      $1::variant AS MESSAGE,
      SPLIT_PART(METADATA$FILENAME,'/',4) AS FILE_NAME,
      current_timestamp::timestamp_ntz  as LOAD_TS
    FROM @DEV.STAGE.DEV_STG/input/  
)
    pattern = 'File_DLYERR_.*'
```

Comment: Have you tried using the list function on the stage?

Comment: @JatinMorar Thanks for your reply. I have used list function but not sure how it will help in this scenario.

Comment: After using it try SELECT * FROM TABLE(result_scan(last_query_id())); This will return the names of the files stored in the stage. Use the results based on your requirement to store them into a table.

Comment: Thanks again, my requirement is slightly different. I have updated the original question.